# Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code? Angular6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from '../contact.service';
import { Contact } from '../contact';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
  providers: [ContactService]
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {
  contacts: Contact[];
  contact: Contact;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  phone: string;

  constructor(public contactService: ContactService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactService.getContacts()
      .subscribe(contacts =>
        this.contacts = contacts)
  }

}
```

I cant seem to understand why this doesn't work. It works if i remove the constructor. Please help, I'm learning angular so cant understand what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Add more information about your issues. What error are you getting ? and add your component html.

Comment: Please choose a title that describes the issue instead of asking for help in it.

Comment: What is the error mesage?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the contacts as an empty array,

```
 contacts: Contact[] = [];
```

your template should be as follows,

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
 <h1>{{contact.first_name}} {{contact.last_name}} {{contact.phone}} </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the blank screen

Comment: <p>Testing</p>

<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    {{first_name}}
    {{last_name}}
    {{phone}}
  </div>
</div>